# Get return value from html dropdown appended from html.append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, onchange

I am trying to generate a dynamic dropdown on a `mouse over` event over an object. I accomplished it like so,

```
  canvas.on('mouse:move', function (e) {

      $('body').append("<div id='imageDialog' style='position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0'><select id='mySelect' onchange='copy();'><option value='wipro' >wipro</option><option value='Hcl' >Hcl</option><option value='krystal kones' >krystal kones</option></select></div>");

  });
```

This functionality works fine. But there is an issue in my next requirement where I need to capture the selected item when the user selectes an item from the drop down. I know its a long shot but I tried it by having `onchange='copy();'` in the drop down and alerting out the selection made like so,

```
function copy(){
    alert(document.getElementById("imageDialog").value);
}
```

But as expected it gave the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: copy is not defined`.

I was at this for some time and had no luck whatsoever and I would really appreciate any help from you experts regarding this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand some of these design decisions (generating select boxes is an odd way to do a dropdown menu) but we'll skip that part for now and get to the good stuff.

When you add new elements to the DOM after initial load, you need to think of event binding a little differently. Since these initial elements weren't around when you first said "Hey, all elements do this when I hover on you", the way you handle it is by telling a parent element instead. Sticking in jQuery-land:

`$('.parent-element').on('click', '.child-element', function (){ });`

This gives you the same result as assigning click directly to `.child-element` if it was around at initial render. You can read more about delegated events here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Here's a fiddle that cleans up your stuff a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/g6r8k6dk/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. I will check on this post back :)

Answer (score 0):

without using pure javascript, use jQuery like the following code.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
   $('#imageDialog').on('click',function(){
       alert($('#imageDialog select').value);
   })
})
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this :) i will check and post back

Comment: Hi the answer was not actually I expected. thanks alot for the help. the answer posted by Zach Dunn works for me :)